# Wrong answer with RSolve function

Tags: recursion

The green function is defined as:

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}G_{0}=1 \\ G_{k}=\sum_{j=1}^{k} \phi^{\prime} G_{k-j},\quad k \geqslant 1\end{array}\right.$

where

$\phi_{j}^{\prime}=\left\{\begin{array}{l}\phi_{j}, 1 \leqslant j \leqslant 2 \\ 0, j>2\end{array}\right.$

I want to use RSolve to get the sequence function of $G$,

```
RSolve[{g[0] == 1, 
g[k] == Sum[
If[j > 2, 0, Subscript[\[Phi], j]]*g[k - j], {j, 1, k}]}, g[k], k]
```

However, the answer contains $\phi_j$ which should be $\phi_1$ or $\phi_2$.

[image: Solution with phi_j]

**Update & Solution**

Thanks to @user64494, I edit the code and get the right answer.

Notice that when k=1, k-j may be a negative index, so g[1] should be added manually.

The code would be:

```
RSolve[{g[0] == 1, g[1] == Subscript[\[Phi], 1], 
  g[k] == Sum[Subscript[\[Phi], j]*g[k - j], {j, 1, 2}]}, g[k], k]
```

And the solution is:

$$
g(k)\to \frac{2^{-k-1} \left(\sqrt{\phi _1^2+4 \phi _2} \left(\phi _1-\sqrt{\phi _1^2+4 \phi _2}\right){}^k-\phi _1 \left(\phi _1-\sqrt{\phi _1^2+4 \phi _2}\right){}^k+\sqrt{\phi _1^2+4 \phi _2} \left(\sqrt{\phi _1^2+4 \phi _2}+\phi _1\right){}^k+\phi _1 \left(\sqrt{\phi _1^2+4 \phi _2}+\phi _1\right){}^k\right)}{\sqrt{\phi _1^2+4 \phi _2}}
$$

But I still wonder **why there's a $\phi_j$ in the previous solution**. I assume every $\phi$ should be evaluated before getting the solution, is this right?

Comment: `RSolve[{g[0] == 1, 
  g[k] == Sum[Subscript[\[Phi], j]*g[k - j], {j, 1, 2}]}, g[k], k]
`  results in an expresssion  with only $\phi_1,\phi_2,k$ and two constants $c_1,c_2$.

Comment: @user64494 Indeed, but the answer is still different from what it should be. I edit the question, thanks!

Comment: I would suspect that `Subscript` has some trouble and interferes with `RSolve` because `RSolve[{g[0] == 1, g[k] == Sum[If[j > 2, 0, f[\[Phi], j]]*g[k - j], {j, 1, k}]}, g[k], k]` (`Subscript` replaced with `f`) doesn't give the wrong answer (indeed doesn't give any answer).

Comment: Wouldn't this simplify to a 2-term recurrence? `In[317]:= RSolve[{gG[k] == phi1*gG[k - 1] + phi2*gG[k - 2], 
  gG[0] == 1}, gG[k], k]

Out[317]= {{gG[
    k] -> -2^-k (-(phi1 + Sqrt[phi1^2 + 4 phi2])^
       k - (phi1 - Sqrt[phi1^2 + 4 phi2])^k C[
       1] + (phi1 + Sqrt[phi1^2 + 4 phi2])^k C[1])}}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, I updated the solution, need to add gG[1]==phi1 manually in case there are c1 in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach using [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[ϕ[n_]] = Subscript[ϕ, n];

phi[j_] = Piecewise[{{ϕ[j], 1 <= j <= 2}}];

g2[0] = 1;

g2[k_Integer?Positive] := g2[k] = 
 Sum[phi[j]*g2[k - j], {j, 1, k}]//Simplify

seq = Table[{k, g2[k]}, {k, 0, 7}] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
g[k_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, k]
```

[image]

Checking,

```
And @@ Table[g[k] == g2[k], {k, 0, 20}] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot!